# CSS3 keyframe animation with 2-3 sec START delay (not iterate)

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I would like the below to start animating AFTER about a 2-3 seconds delay.

Anyone have any idea as to how to add a delay to start of CSS3 keyframe animation like below? *(jQuery is not preffered, but if I must)*

```
.coin{  
  animation: animationFrames ease 2.5s;
  -webkit-animation: animationFrames ease 2.5s; /* Safari 4+ */
  animation-iteration-count: 8;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 8;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin:  50% 50%;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  max-width: 55px;
  position:relative;
  top: 63px;
  left: 195px;
}
```

*and:*

```
  @-webkit-keyframes animationFrames {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform:  translate(-402px,55px)  ;
      }
      4% {
        -webkit-transform:  translate(-333px,26px)  ;
      }
      9% {
        -webkit-transform:  translate(-257px,-13px)  ;
      }
      14% {
        -webkit-transform:  translate(-183px,-18px)  ;
      }
```

Comment: Yes, I assume .coin. Also, see my update answer to inlcude 'transition-delay'

Comment: See my update to use 'animate-delay' instead

Comment: I used jQuery to get my result.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
animation-delay: 2s;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

Comment: I updated my question -- where would I put that? on .coin ?

Comment: I don't see any different at all... I added it on .coin

Comment: @Nooneknows yes you add it to .coin

Comment: But what happens is... the .coin starts with no delay, but Iterates with a delay

Comment: @Nooneknows, did you remove 'animation-iteration-count: 8;' to prevent the iteration?

Comment: I need that... I just need the delay on start -- might end up just sing jQuery with this.